# Dynamically retrieving a listener instance by class

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I've made a system for retrieving listener classes by passing a specific class to a getter method. As an example, you can call it like so:

```
GlobalListener lis = /*Manager instance*/.getListener(GlobalListener.class);
```

Where `/*Manager instance*/` is an instance of my `ListenerManager` class that contains the following abbreviated content:

```
public class ListenerManager {

    private final Project project;
    private final Map<String, SubListener> listeners = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * {@link ListenerManager} constructor
     * 
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @version 1.0.0
     * 
     * @param plugin The main {@link Project} instance
     */
    public ListenerManager(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
        this.registerDefaults();
    }

    private void registerDefaults() {
        SubListener[] list = new SubListener[] {
            new GlobalListener(this.project),
            new ItemListener(this.project)
        };

        for (SubListener lis : list) {
            this.registerListener(lis);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets a listener by its string name. Returns null if the listener is
     * disabled or not registered.
     * 
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @version 1.0.0
     * 
     * @param <T> The SubListener class
     * @param listener An instance of the class type extending
     *                 {@link SubListener} to retrieve
     * @return The listener class, null if disabled or not registered
     */
    public <T extends SubListener> T getListener(Class<T> listener) {
        return listener.cast(this.listeners.get(this.getListenerName(listener)));
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a listener's name
     */
    protected String getListenerName(Class<? extends SubListener> listener) {
        try {
            Method m = listener.getDeclaredMethod("getName");
            return (String) m.invoke(null);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
            this.project.getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Error reflecting listener field for name!", ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Registers a listener through the plugin manager and {@link ListenerManager}
     * 
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @version 1.0.0
     * 
     * @param <T> The {@link SubListener} to register
     * @param listener The listener to register
     * @throws ListenerReregisterException Attempted to register a Listener under a similar key
     */
    public <T extends SubListener> void registerListener(T listener) throws ListenerReregisterException {
        String name = listener.getName();
        if (!this.listeners.containsKey(name)) {
            this.listeners.put(name, listener);
            this.project.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(listener, this.plugin);
        } else {
            throw new ListenerReregisterException("Listener Map already contains key: " + name);
        }
    }

}
```

As seen, it reflects the `SubListener` class for the method `getName` via `Method#invoke(null)`, which is final inside of the `SubListener` class:

```
public class SubListener implements Listener {

    private final Project project;

    public SubListener(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return this.getClass().getName() + "@" + this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
    }

}
```

However, upon my latest testing this system no longer seems to work anymore, where it had worked perfectly fine in the past. Now the line `m.invoke(null)` throws a `NoSuchMethodException`. I would assume that is because I passed a `null` to the `#invoke` parameter, but how would it have worked perfectly fine beforehand but is just now breaking?

Note that I can't really opt to make the `getName` method static, as it works by getting the current class' name through `this.getClass()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the [`Method#invoke(Object, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) method, which accepts an accessor instance as its first parameter.

Passing `null` as first arg would be perfectly fine if the method was marked `static`, but your method is an instance method, as you mentioned and as is proven by your posted code. (I'm assuming that you're not having a static method `getName()` on each listener)

I can't fully answer why it worked before - My only guess is that you may not have called the method as I cannot see *any* way one could call an instance method without an instance.

A possible solution to your problem is just using `getClass().getName()` as a key for listeners since you have the class when you're saving the instance and when you're fetching it. Also, your `getName()` method does not provide a key more unique than my approach - It just returns it in another format.

*Side note: `Class#getName()` already returns the Fully Qualified Name of a class, no need to return the package name too - Your method would result in stuff like `my.package.Class@my.package`.*

Comment: Yeah, simply using the FQN of the class seems a bit better, especially since listeners should be effectively singleton anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

That should have not worked before, as `Method#invoke(null)` invokes the method as though it is a static, which means no reference to an instance. This should not have worked unless you had a static `getName()`.

You are either going to have to

A) Have an instance of the Listener get passed in place of null (`Method#invoke(instance)`)

B) Have `getName()` be a static method, which depending on what Project is, may not work